# Jquery Tooltip onShow function

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

I am trying to use a function inside the tooltip onShow event. I'm sure it's simple and straightforward but I just can't get it working. What am I missing here?

```
$("input[title]").tooltip({
    onShow: function() {
        $('.tooltip').css({'cursor':'crosshair', 'border-style':'dashed'}).click(function () {
            alert();
        });
    },
    offset: [120, 0]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aya3C/1/

Thx in advance

Comment: You get the alert in the click function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click()` event is overrided by tooltip plugin. Try to use `mousedown()` instead.

See there: http://jsfiddle.net/aya3C/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. Every time I click the tooltip the alert displays +1. Would you happen to know how I prevent that?